# Rails build method nested resources with blogs and posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, blogs

I am creating an app using Ruby on Rails and in the Admin panel there are `blogs` and `posts` controllers. The routes for the admin area looks like this:

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
  scope :module => "admin" do
    root to: "pages#index"
    resources :blogs do
      resources :posts, :controller => "posts"
    end
  end
end
```

What I have is `http://admin.mydomain.com/blogs` showing the blogs with `/blogs/2/` showing the posts on that blog.

What I want is for when creating a new post at `/blogs/2/posts/new` that the `blog_id` is attached to the post.

In the `admin/posts_controller.rb` I have this as the create action

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

At the moment it just creates a post. I want to link that post to the current blog id which is in the URL - `/blog/2`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this and does depend on how you're actually using the controller. If you just edit posts at /blogs/1/xxxx then you can do this:

The blog_id will be available as `params[:blog_id]`. I'd usually create a before_filter to find the blog and then do the rest in the create action:

```
before_filter do
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
end

def create
  @post = @blog.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to [@blog, @post], notice: 'Post created successfully'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the power of ActiveRecord associations for this, something like this should work:

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if @blog
    @post = @blog.posts.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    end
  end

  render :new  
end
```

First find the blog post, which will, according to your route will be the :id in the params hash.  Next use `@blog.posts.new` to create a new post associated with that blog.